# get json object from apache solr using java for autocomplete

Tags: java, mysql, json, apache, solr

I did apache solr indexing (mysql) data, its searching by select and suggest, how to get json object dynamically from apache solr while keyup the characters, Here I am given apache solr URL and its corresponding results

### URL

```
localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=hotelName%3A%22Royal+Orchid%22&wt=json&indent=true
```

### output

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "hotelName:\"Royal Orchid\"",
      "_": "1403088370128",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 20,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "hotelName": [
          "Royal Orchid Metropole Mysore"
        ],
        "cityName": "Mysore",
        "id": "224433",
        "_version_": 1471227815192952800
      },
      {
        "hotelName": [
          "Royal Orchid Central Bangalore"
        ],
        "cityName": "Bengaluru (and vicinity)",
        "id": "240388",
        "_version_": 1471227815235944400
      },
      {
        "hotelName": [
          "Royal Orchid Central Jaipur"
        ],
        "cityName": "Jaipur",
        "id": "258200",
        "_version_": 1471227815290470400
      },
      {
        "hotelName": [
          "Royal Orchid Brindavan Gardens"
        ],
        "cityName": "Mysore",
        "id": "258917",
        "_version_": 1471227815293616000
      },
      {
        "hotelName": [
          "Royal Orchid Central Pune"
        ],
        "cityName": "Pune",
        "id": "267814",
        "_version_": 1471227815330316300
      },
      {
        "hotelName": [
          "Royal Orchid Suites"
        ],
        "cityName": "Bengaluru (and vicinity)",
        "id": "309427",
        "_version_": 1471227815379599400
      },
      {
        "hotelName": [
          "Royal Orchid Central Ahmedabad"
        ],
        "cityName": "Ahmedabad",
        "id": "326301",
        "_version_": 1471227815444611000
      },
      {
        "hotelName": [
          "Royal Orchid Fort Resort"
        ],
        "cityName": "Mussoorie",
        "id": "327797",
        "_version_": 1471227815467679700
      },
      {
        "hotelName": [
          "Royal Orchid Resort Pattaya"
        ],
        "cityName": "Pattaya",
        "id": "344270",
        "_version_": 1471227815546323000
      },
      {
        "hotelName": [
          "Royal Orchid Central Grazia"
        ],
        "cityName": "Navi Mumbai",
        "id": "350799",
        "_version_": 1471227815558905900
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to call apache solr url from JQuery for autocomplete or Shall I write RESTful client for to get JSON data, pls help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your JavaScript is also running in `localhost:8983`. If not, the call would violate the cross-domain policy of the browser.

If it is not, you need to create a simple backend bouncer on the same domain as your website. So, if your SOLR is running at `localhost:8983` and your website is running at `localhost:80`, you need a backend helper for the JavaScript.

The JS in question is quite simple, you can use `$.get` or `$.getJSON`. I recommend getJSON for this, see the documentation and examples at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/.

I have no clue how your backend is built, but a c# mvc ajax controller action to do the bouncing would look something like this. Note that I just wrote it without testing, this will not work for you directly but you can use it as a guideline.

```
    public JsonResult Search(string searchTerm)
    {
        // if your searchterm is the value for "q". You might have to encode it.
        var url = "localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=" + searchTerm + "&wt=json&indent=true";

        DoxLog.Info("Contacting Sovelia API url: " + url);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UserAgent = "Dox";

        // Fire request
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
            {
                var responseAsString = reader.ReadToEnd();

                return Json(responseAsString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Implementing Autocomplete in SOLR you must use the Terms Component of SOLR. It is most efficient way for implementing AutoComplete Feature in SOLR.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent

For getting the JSON rsponse from Java code I will use following code:

```
String callbackResponse = "";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

SearchResponse searchResponse = new SearchResponse();
searchResponse = <response from SOLR >
callbackResponse = mapper.writeValueAsString(searchResponse);

return callbackResponse;
```

Both the Things are working perfectly fine for me.

Hope this helps you in resolving your issue.